# Haskell, mapping String to Maybe a

Tags: haskell, lambda, types

This question is already solved, it is a mapping from a String to a "Maybe a", with empty,insert,lookup functions as defined below, i'm unable to understand the solution.

The code:

```
type Map a = String -> Maybe a

empty :: Map a
empty = \x -> Nothing

insert :: (String, a) -> Map a -> Map a
insert (s, a) m = \x -> if x == s then Just a else m x

lookup :: String -> Map a -> Maybe a
lookup x m = m x
```

empty and lookup i think i understand.

insert however is puzzling to me,the lambda inside it i don't understand, how is x used in the equality when it is never taken as a parameter, x is from what i can see is a String, but it isn't given a value anywhere.
what would be the resulting function from `insert ("foo", 61) empty` how would it be evaluated, and what does x represent?

also why would a line like this work and return "Just 61"
`lookup "foo" (insert ("foo", 61) empty)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we say `type Map a = String -> Maybe a`, it is just a type alias, so `Map a` is identical to `String -> Maybe a`. Thus, you know that `Map a` is just a function type `String -> Maybe a`.

Therefore, when we say `empty :: Map a`, we want to define `empty` as a function from `String` to `Maybe a`. In this example, we have defined it as `\x -> Nothing`, which means `empty` is an empty map that maps every string `x` to `Noting`.

So we can look into `insert :: (String, a) -> Map a -> Map a` using the same method. The meaning for this function is to add one more mapping relation (i.e., `(String, a)` pair) to a given `Map a`, and the return value is a new `Map a` which contains the added pair.
Therefore, by pattern matching `insert (s, a) m`, `s` is of type `String`, `a` is of type `a`, and `m` is of type `Map a`. Now we have to construct the result, which is of type `Map a`. Recall that `Map a` is just `String -> Maybe a`, so we have to construct a function here. To construct a function, we use the lambda expression here.

So by using lambda expression `\x -> if x == s then Just a else m x`, we are saying that this new `Map a` (function of type `String -> Maybe a`) takes a `String` `x`, and checks if it is equal to `s` (the string inserted this time). If it is not `s`, we use the old `Map a` (`m`) to check the remaining mapping.

The example could be calculated as:

```
  lookup "foo" (insert ("foo", 61) empty)
  {applying lookup}
= (insert ("foo", 61) empty) "foo"
  {applying insert}
= (\x -> if x == "foo" then Just 61 else (empty x)) "foo"
  {applying lambda expression, replacing x with "foo"}
= if "foo" == "foo" then Just 61 else (empty "foo")
  {applying if_then_else}
= Just 61
```

Answer (score 2):

A `Map a` is a function; `x` is the parameter of that function. Looking up a key in a map just means calling the map on the key.

Consider the lookup of `"foo"` in a map than maps `"foo"` to `3`.

```
lookup "foo" (insert ("foo", 3) empty)
   -- by the definition of lookup
   == (insert ("foo", 3) empty) "foo"
   -- by the definition of insert
   == (\x -> if x == "foo" then Just 3 else empty x) "foo"
   -- apply function to "foo"
   == if "foo" == "foo" then Just 3 else empty "foo"
   -- take the true branch
   == Just 3
```

Now consider the lookup of `"bar"` in the same map.

```
lookup "bar" (insert ("foo", 3) empty)
   == (insert ("foo", 3) empty) "bar"
   == (\x -> if x == "foo" then Just 3 else empty x) "bar"
   == if "bar" == "foo" then Just 3 else empty "bar"
   -- take the false branch
   == empty "bar"
   -- by definition of empty
   == (\x -> Nothing) "bar"
   -- apply function to "bar"
   == Nothing
```